# Apex class is failing

Tags: apex, soql, exception, governorlimits

I have a requirement like need to display related opportunities for a specific lead with some criterias like sic,state,city.

- sic starts with criteria like sic in lead is 123 i need to
  opportunities like 123,1234
- Sic with state
- Sic with state & city

Now everything is working fine in sandbox.But, in production also working but in some cases it failed to retrive records.Because of SOQL queries: 101 exception.Now, with try/catch blocks i am displaying exception to the user.But i want to fix this permanent.Let me know better usecase to resolve.

My short version of code

```
public class LeadController 
{
    public String CurrentId;
    public Set<String> codes;
    public List<Opportunity> listopp{get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> Mainlist;

    public LeadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     CurrentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }

    public void search()
    {
        set<String> cityset=new set<String>();
        codes = new Set<String>();
        Map<String,String> citymap=new Map<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> statemap=new Map<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> Siccodes=new Map<String,String>();
        List<Opportunity> Mainlist=new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Opportunity> newopplist=new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Opportunity> siccount=new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Opportunity> Citycount=new List<Opportunity>();
        Mainlist=null;
        siccount=null;
        Citycount=null;
        for(Lead ld:[Select Id,City,State,SIC_Code_1__c from Lead where Id=:CurrentId ])
        {
            // cityset.add(ld.City);
            if(ld.City <> null)
            {
                citymap.put(ld.City.toUpperCase(),ld.City);
            }
            if(ld.state <> null)
            {
                statemap.put(ld.State.toUpperCase(),ld.State);
            }
            if(ld.SIC_Code_1__c <> null)
            {
            Siccodes.put(ld.SIC_Code_1__c, ld.SIC_Code_1__c);
            }
        }
        newopplist=[Select Id,Name,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,StageName,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                    Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                    account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' ];
        listopp=new List<Opportunity>();
        if(Siccodes != null && !Siccodes.isEmpty())
            { 
                for(String code:Siccodes.keySet())
                {
                    codes.add(code + '%');
                }
            }
        listopp.clear();
        System.debug('Enter in SIC**** '+'Sic loop');
        for (Opportunity opp:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                         Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                         account.No_of_active_units__c from opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                         LIKE :codes ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
                {
                    if(opp.account.SIC_Code__c <> null)
                    {
                        listopp.add(opp);
                    }
                }
        Citycount =null;
        System.debug('End SIC Loop****'+listopp);
        siccount = listopp.clone();
        for(Opportunity opp: newopplist)
        {
             if(statemap.containskey(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) && siccount !=null && !siccount.isEmpty())
            {
                listopp.clear();
                System.debug('Sic with State loop ***');
                for(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,
                         Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                         account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                         LIKE :codes AND Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                         and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
                {
                    System.debug('State Info with sic'+opps.Billing_State_Province__c);
                    if(opps.Billing_State_Province__c <> null)
                    {
                        listopp.add(opps);
                        System.debug('State Opportunity Id'+opps.id);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('Data in Sic State **** '+listopp);
                Mainlist=listopp.clone();
            }
        }
        if(Mainlist!= null && !Mainlist.isEmpty() )
        {
        For(Opportunity opp:newopplist)
        {
            if(citymap.containsKey(opp.Billing_City__c) && statemap.containskey(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) )
            {
                listopp.clear();
                Citycount=null;
                System.debug('Data in Sic State & City');
                for(Opportunity oppsd:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                         Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                         account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                         LIKE :codes AND Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                         AND Billing_City__c =:citymap.get(opp.Billing_City__c) and 
                         StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
                {
                    if(oppsd.Billing_City__c <> null)
                    {
                        listopp.add(oppsd);
                        System.debug('Opportunity Id'+oppsd.id);
                    }
                    System.debug('Data in Third Condition'+listopp);
                }
                Citycount=listopp;
                System.debug('Data in Sic State & City loop '+listopp);
            } 
        }
        }
    }
}
```

As per debug logs.I'm getting exception on line 71

```
for(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,
                         Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                         account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                         LIKE :codes AND Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                         and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
```

Comment: Query in a `for` loop...

Comment: Multiple queries in a `for` loop, you need to build your `Map` and loop through that

Comment: Because I need to filter with opportunity. Will you guide me feasible way to check

Comment: @Pavantej you could try it out keeping SOQL query outside of `for` loop and update your question if you are facing any issues